# How to improve when starting out in data science

Tags: bigdata, data-science-model, data-analysis

A little bit of background info,I recently started a new job as a data analyst where I have to use data to provide insights on the IT operations and devops process of my company.

I’m fresh out of college, I have a bachelors in engineering, which covered the basics of statistics such as discrete/continuous probability distributions, naïve bayes probability and some hypothesis testing. Regarding data science, I used Splunk to analyze machine data and applied a few basic machine learning models during an internship and taught myself how to use some python libraries such as pandas and numpy.

But now I’ve hit a brick wall, I don’t really know how to apply the statistics that I’ve learnt, and how probability distributions and hypothesis testing all gel together to provide insight. My immediate task involves providing some insights, machine learning will come at a later stage and although I am interested, I intend to work on it later.

My question is, where do I go from here? Are there any books that I can read that provide examples on how to apply the statistical theories that I’ve learnt? Most ebooks that I’ve found don’t really touch much on this, and most internet articles give examples in a business context, which I don’t find helpful or applicable.

Comment: Try some problems on Kaggle!

Comment: Searching Google will help..

Answer (score 1):

I tend to recommend [Applied Predictive Modeling](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/).  It serves as a nice bridge between theory and application.  The organization of the book, which is essentially data prep, pick model, and validate is what one does in the real world (at least at a high level.)  Plus there's plenty of R examples and datasets you can try things.

As far as statistics, I think you just have to go out and learn more of it.  Basic statistics is often insufficient to do anything meaningful in the real world.  The only real way that it comes together is by learning something and then applying it to something.

A comment suggested kaggle.  I personally wouldn't do kaggle for the competitions but rather for the data.  I like to find relevant datasets and use models i'm toying around with as a way to learn more about them.  For example, when I have interns, I give them the zillow housing dataset and show how different generalized linear models work and how each change can improve or decrease model performance.

In short, I suggest reading Applied Predictive Modeling, take some courses in Coursera and apply that knowledge to real datasets.  By learning and then doing, you'll be amazed at how quickly you learn and how much easier it becomes to grasp more advance techniques and applications.